# Looking up subnet ids dynamically using a tag value in Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to pass a list of ingress rules to an aws_security_group resource. Rules are stored as a list of maps:

```
 ingress = [
  {
    "from_port": 443,
    "to_port": 443,
    "protocol": "tcp",
    "subnet_roles": [ "web" ]
  },
  {
    "from_port": 3389,
    "to_port": 3389,
    "protocol": "tcp",
    "subnet_roles": [ "private","management" ]
  }
]
```

I'm passing these values through a module declaration and, while doing so, need to look up the CIDR blocks corresponding to the 'subnet_roles' variable. In my top level module declaration, I'm trying this:

```
 ingress_rules = [ for rule in each.value.rules.ingress : merge(rule,
                   { cidr_blocks = [ 
                     for role in rule.subnet_roles : 
                      lookup(module.aws_vpc.subnets_by_role[role], "cidr_block", null)
                     ]
                    }
                  )]
```

But this is resulting in the error: "Invalid value for "inputMap" parameter: lookup() requires a map as the first argument." But, subnets_by_role[role] is a map here's how it's constructed:

```
      subnets_by_role = merge(
          { for subnet in aws_subnet.public :
              subnet.tags.subnet_role => subnet...
          },
          {
          for subnet in aws_subnet.private :
            subnet.tags.subnet_role => subnet...
          }
        )
```

I'm not clear why lookup isn't accepting the map from subnets_by_role.

Answer (score 0):

`subnets_by_role` is `map(list(string)`, or written another way, `key => list(string)`. Thus `module.aws_vpc.subnets_by_role[role]` returns a list. Am I missing something here?